# Revert scan state when prompting for variable values

Tags: sql, oracle, installation, sql-update

How do you detect the current `SCAN` state and revert it after changing it?

An exerpt from the script in question:

```
SET SCAN OFF
SET ECHO ON
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON

SET SCAN ON
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET CREATED_BY = &&created_by;
SET SCAN OFF
```

The problem is that if the script doesn't have the first line (`SET SCAN OFF`), then the code to prompt the user should not turn the `SCAN` state off afterwards. The pseudocode solution:

```
-- The next line might not exist, or be "SET SCAN ON".
SET SCAN OFF
SET ECHO ON
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON

-- Remember if the scanning was on or off.
PUSH SCAN STATE
SET SCAN ON
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET CREATED_BY = &&created_by;

-- Revert scanning to its former state.
POP SCAN STATE
```

The line `PUSH SCAN STATE` remembers the state so that if the code is altered by removing the first line, the rest of the script still works as expected, due to the corresonding `POP SCAN STATE`.

Comment: You could `SHOW SCAN` at the top and reset it afterwards manually if necessary.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Am looking for an automated solution.

Comment: I gathered that, which is why I made the comment but not an answer - I suspect there may be no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sql*plus `STORE` command is supposed to do this, unfortunately it doesn't seem to save the `SCAN` state (SQL*Plus 9.2.0.1.0). I will demonstrate with another setting (`TIMING`):

```
SQL> show timing
timing OFF
SQL> -- save parameters into an os file
SQL> store set param.sql create
Created file param.sql
SQL> -- run script
SQL> SET TIMING ON
SQL> show timing
timing ON
SQL> -- reset state
SQL> @param.sql
SQL> show timing
timing OFF
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Good idea and provides me with an area to explore. Too bad it doesn't actually solve the problem.